# AJAX echo not returning but php register to database works

Tags: php, ajax

UPDATE:

Code is written as is and will stay that way. However, now it doesn't submit the data the user wrote in the form to the database. What's wrong.

Here is the first file. It contains the XML HTTP REQUEST and html form. This file also contains the wild .

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

<head>

 <?php
 require_once 'core/init.php';
 ?>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />        

    <title></title> 

    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js">

 //directly below is that wild script tag

 </script>




 <script type="text/javascript">

 function load(thefile, thediv) {

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

} else {

    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

    }


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {



document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;   

    }

}   

parameters1 = 'username='+document.getElementById('username').value;
parameters2 = 'email='+document.getElementById('email').value;
parameters3 = 'password='+document.getElementById('password').value;
parameters4 = 'password_again='+document.getElementById('password_again').value;
parameters5 = 'first_name='+document.getElementById('first_name').value;
parameters6 = 'last_name='+document.getElementById('last_name').value;

xmlhttp.open('POST', thefile, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(parameters1 + '&' + parameters2 + '&' + parameters3 + '&' + 

    parameters4 + '&' + parameters5 + '&' +parameters6);

 }

 </script>

    </script>   

    <title>Pop Up Sign Up</title>


</head>

    <body>

<div id="popupbox"> 

        <form name="signup" action="" method="post">

            Desired Username:

<input id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo 

    (isset($desired_username) ? strip_tags($desired_username) : '');?>" type="text" 

    placeholder="Bob123" name="username" size="14" />

            <br />   <br /> 

            Your Email:
            Register
<input id="email" placeholder="jasontanner328@gmail.com" value="<?php echo 

    (isset($desired_email) ? strip_tags($desired_email) : '');?>" type="email" 

    name="email" size="14" />

            <br />   <br /> 

            Your Password:

<input id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" 

    size="14" />

            <br />  <br />      

            Your Password Again:

<input id="password_again" placeholder="Password Again" 

    name="password_again" type="password" size="14" />

            <br />  <br />  

            First Name:

<input id="first_name" placeholder="Jason" value="<?php echo 

    (isset($desired_first_name) ? strip_tags($desired_first_name) : '');?>" 

    name="first_name" type="text" size="14" />

            <br />  <br />  

            Last Name:

<input id="last_name" placeholder="Tanner" name="last_name" value="<?php echo 

    (isset($desired_last_name) ? strip_tags($desired_last_name) : '');?>" type="text" 

    size="14" />

            <br />  <br />  

<center><input type="button" name="submit" value="Register" 

    onclick="load('register.php', 'popupbox');" /></center>

        </form>



</div> 



 <span id="result">



 </span>


 </body>

 </html>
```

Here is the second file that deals with inserting the data into the server and what I want to return after the submit button has been clicked on.

```
   <?php

require_once 'core/init.php';
logged_in_redirect();
if (empty($_POST) === false) {


$desired_username = $_POST['username'];
$desired_email = $_POST['email'];
$desired_first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$desired_last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

$required_fields = array 

('username','email','password','password_again','first_name','last_name');

foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {

if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {

    $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required.';

break 1;    
                                                                                         }
                                            }

if (empty($errors) === true)    {
if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true || strlen($_POST ['username']) < 6) {

$errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \''    . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already taken 

or is too short. 6 characters are the minimum.';
                                                                                                                    }

if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST ['username']) == true) {
$errors[] = 'Sorry there is a space in your username.';         
                                                                                }

if (strlen($_POST ['password']) < 6)    {
$errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
                                                            }

if ($_POST ['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
$errors[] = 'Make sure both passwords submitted are the same.';     
                                                                                }   

if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
$errors[] = 'A valid email address is required.';
                                                                                                }   

if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
$errors[] = 'Sorry, the email \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' is already in use.';
                                                                    }

if (strlen($_POST ['first_name']) < 2) {
$errors[] = 'Your first name must contain at least two characters.';
                                                  }
if (strlen($_POST ['last_name']) < 2) {
$errors[] = 'Your last name must contain at least two characters.';
                                                  } }
                                                    } else {


//if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {

//echo 'You have successfully registered. Please check your email to activate your 

account.';  

//  } else {

if (empty ($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
    $register_data = array(
    'username'              => $_POST['username'],      
    'password'              => $_POST['password'],
    'first_name'            => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name'             => $_POST['last_name'],
    'email'                     => $_POST['email'],
    'email_code'            => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
                                 );

    register_user($register_data);


echo 'WIN';                                     



//      header('Location: register.php?success');
//      exit();

//  } else 

if (empty($errors) === false){
    echo output_errors($errors);
         }
}}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to help you, since **all** of the relevant code is missing.  You've posted everything but the important part.

Comment: Show us the Firebug or Dev tools' Net output. :)

Comment: Firebug came up with nothing.

Comment: @jason328, If Firebug truly came up with "nothing" then your JavaScript isn't working, as no request is being made.

Comment: How is it then that my database receives the registered data? I changed my submit button to a button button and now I have different errors unrelated to the current issue. I'll take a look at it and update the question with the code without brevity.

Comment: Your edit, that shows all code, is missing closing curly braces in the POST page; `if (empty($_POST) === false) {` is never closed, nor is the `} else {` block for the `if (empty($errors) === true) {` block.

Comment: I'm sorry. My editor has all the curly braces as added. And even if I didn't I would have gotten a syntax error, but I didn't. Even after changing the button I'm still not getting the echo returned after the button is pressed.

Comment: It's quite difficult to help debug logic errors when the syntax is (displayed) invalid; a simple missing curly-brace can change the entire flow of the program. Please try to update with the correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I keep updating the code and it's hard to keep the question code up to date as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button on your form is `type="submit"`; This will submit the form and redirect the page, unless you have it `return false;` in the `onclick` attribute. I would suggest, rather, to change the button to a regular button instead of a submit-button:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Register" onclick="load('register.php', 'result');" />
```

This change will stop your page from redirecting after submitting the form.

**EDIT**: After reviewing the full code, the POST-page looks like it has a logic error in the processing (and a few syntax errors; see my comment on the question regarding closing curly braces).

The `if (empty($errors) === true) {` block ends with an `} else {` and inside the else-block you output that the user has successfully registered. Translated, this means "if there is an initial error, tell the user they successfully registered." Instead, change everything after (and including) the `} else {` to:

```
if (!empty($_POST) && empty($errors)) {
    // the form has been submitted and there are no errors
    echo 'You have successfully registered. Please check your email to activate your account.';
    $register_data = array(
    'username'              => $_POST['username'],      
    'password'              => $_POST['password'],
    'first_name'            => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name'             => $_POST['last_name'],
    'email'                     => $_POST['email'],
    'email_code'            => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
                                 );
    register_user($register_data);
} else if (!empty($errors)) {
    // there are errors =[
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
```

Comment: I'm just going to post the code in full. That will make things easier.

Comment: I appreciate the help and patience with me. It has been a long night. From now on I'll double check what I post on here versus what is in my text editor.